# Require liblttng when I install the ceph in CentOS7.2

Tags: ceph

When I install the `ceph` and `ceph-radosgw` in my CentOS 7.2:

```
yum -y install ceph ceph-radosgw
```

I get the below error:

```
......
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: 1:ceph-base-10.2.9-0.el7.x86_64 (Ceph)
           Requires: liblttng-ust.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: 1:ceph-radosgw-10.2.9-0.el7.x86_64 (Ceph)
           Requires: libfcgi.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: 1:ceph-mon-10.2.9-0.el7.x86_64 (Ceph)
           Requires: libleveldb.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: 1:ceph-common-10.2.9-0.el7.x86_64 (Ceph)
           Requires: libbabeltrace-ctf.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: 1:librados2-10.2.9-0.el7.x86_64 (Ceph)
           Requires: liblttng-ust.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: 1:ceph-osd-10.2.9-0.el7.x86_64 (Ceph)
           Requires: libleveldb.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: 1:librgw2-10.2.9-0.el7.x86_64 (Ceph)
           Requires: libfcgi.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: 1:ceph-common-10.2.9-0.el7.x86_64 (Ceph)
           Requires: libbabeltrace.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: 1:librbd1-10.2.9-0.el7.x86_64 (Ceph)
           Requires: liblttng-ust.so.0()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Answer (score 2):

An Example for CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core) and Ceph Mimic 13.2.2. All info out of the [Ceph doc](http://docs.ceph.com/docs/master/install/get-packages/#).

```
[root@server1 ]# cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core) 

[root@server1 ]# ceph --version
ceph version 13.2.2 (02899bfda814146b021136e9d8e80eba494e1126) mimic (stable)
```

1. Add keys:

> `sudo rpm --import 'https://download.ceph.com/keys/release.asc'`

2. create a file like:

> /etc/yum.repos.d/ceph.repro

with this content:

> ```
> [ceph]
> name=Ceph packages for $basearch
> baseurl=https://download.ceph.com/rpm-mimic/el7/$basearch
> enabled=1
> priority=2
> gpgcheck=1
> gpgkey=https://download.ceph.com/keys/release.asc
>
> [ceph-noarch]
> name=Ceph noarch packages
> baseurl=https://download.ceph.com/rpm-mimic/el7/noarch
> enabled=1
> priority=2
> gpgcheck=1
> gpgkey=https://download.ceph.com/keys/release.asc
>
> [ceph-source]
> name=Ceph source packages
> baseurl=https://download.ceph.com/rpm-mimic/el7/SRPMS
> enabled=0
> priority=2
> gpgcheck=1
> gpgkey=https://download.ceph.com/keys/release.asc
> ```

3. Download additional packages

> sudo yum install -y
>   https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm

4. Upgrade Ceph

> su -c 'rpm -Uvh
>   https://download.ceph.com/rpm-mimic/el7/noarch/ceph-release-1-1.el7.noarch.rpm'

5. Update

> `sudo yum update`

6. Install your Ceph

> `yum -y install ceph ceph-radosgw`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sudo yum install -y yum-utils && sudo yum-config-manager --add-repo https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/ && sudo yum install --nogpgcheck -y epel-release && sudo rpm --import /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-7 && sudo rm /etc/yum.repos.d/dl.fedoraproject.org*
```

Maybe you use this: http://bbs.ceph.org.cn/question/584

Answer (score 0):

In case of Ubuntu 18.04, try adding the `universe` distribution:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

Source: https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/9876#issuecomment-414854527